# Google Bigquery ML model schema ValueError

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using Google Bigquery ML for the first time and try to train a linear regression model using the following command:

```
%%bigquery
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `sandbox.sample_lr_model`
OPTIONS
    (model_type='linear_reg',
     data_split_method ='no_split',
     max_iterations=1) AS
SELECT
  y AS label,
  x AS x 
FROM
  `sandbox.y2018m08d01_rh_sample_dataframe_to_bq_v01_v01`
```

this step fails with the following error message:

```
ValueError: Table has no schema:  call 'client.get_table()'
```

However the model is created and can be viewed:

[image]

The model has a so-called "Model schema". Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

google-cloud-bigquery==1.4.0 Python 3.5 Ubuntu

My input table is a minimum example:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have `google-cloud-bigquery==1.4.0`? This issue should have been fixed with https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/5602

Comment: restarting the kernel solved the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was fixed in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/5602, which was released in version 1.4.0 of BigQuery. To double-check your BigQuery version, run `!pip freeze | grep bigquery` in a notebook cell.

Note that Datalab does not include the latest version of the `google-cloud-bigquery` library. To upgrade the version, run `!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`.